# Move old backup consisting of zip-files to version control (mercurial)

Tags: version-control, mercurial, backup, tortoisehg

Previously i've been taking backups using zip-files every now and then by just right-clicking my whole project folder, send to zip, and add a small message at the end of the filename.

But now i've discovered how good version control is so i want to move all my old zip-backups into the current repository. Best would be if i could commit it in "before" the initial commit (which is the same as my final zip-file) somehow so it looks like it was a sequential development. But adding it just as a branch wouldn't be too bad either, better than having it in zip-files anyway.

My old backup is about 100 zip-files, with very consistent filenames: `Backup Date Message.zip`

I guess i could quite easily create a bat-file that unzips, commits, deletes and repeats but i'm wondering if there is any better way of doing this. Especially the "insert before" part since i'm not exactly a master in mercurial yet. I almost exclusively use TortoiseHG, not the command-line.

Comment: Why do you need to import your old backups? Can't you just backup what you have *now* by, say, marking current code with a vcs tag?

Comment: My old backups are taking up quite alot of space as they are stored in full instead of diffs. I still might go back and check at certain versions, especially after removing features that might be reimplemented, i remove quite aggressively instead of commenting out. So i still want to keep them and then it's good to have in one place where browsing, diffing, etc is alot easier.

Answer (score 4):

I'd think you would need to script it.  Normally though not everything in a directory archive goes to revision control (generated and intermediate files don't).  You could script something that looks for your "interesting" extensions, and just saves those in revision control.

Sounds like an opportunity if you want to learn some perl or python.  Otherwise, mark today as your start in RCS and forgetaboutit.